# How to efficiency set matrix / array diagonals based on rest of column (avoiding a loop?)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to code a solution that takes a function, and sets the central diagonal values (i.e. along A[0,0], A[1,1], ...., A[N,N]) based on summing the values in the column below the diagonal cell.

An example:

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [3, 0, 0],
              [4, 2, 0]])

B = function_to_be_built(A)

B = np.array([[7, 0, 0],
              [3, 2, 0],
              [4, 2, 0]])
```

where you can see that addition operators for cell [0,0] = 3 + 4 = 7 and for cell [1,1], 2 = 2.

Of course this could be achieved relatively easily using a `for` loop, but the code is designed to be in a central kernel, thus efficiency is critical. I feel like there should be a way to achieve this efficiently using numpy.... something like using `np.tril` so select only the values below the diagonal?

Could anyone perhaps help me get to the solution please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the values above the diagonal of `A` zeros?

Comment: @RafaelMartins `np.diagonal(A)` is [0,0,,,0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the diagonal and upper diagonal are filled with zeros, you can do:

```
In [43]: B = A + np.diag(A.sum(axis=0))

In [44]: B
Out[44]: 
array([[7, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [4, 2, 0]])
```

If you cannot guarantee that these areas are zero, you can do:

```
In [62]: B = A + np.diag(np.tril(A, -1).sum(axis=0))

In [63]: B
Out[63]: 
array([[7, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 0],
       [4, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very similar to DYZ's solution, but (the second option) ran in 6/7 of the time compared to DYZ, hence I opted to select this as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the lower triangular part of `A`, sum it column-wise, convert to a diagonal matrix, and add back to `A`:

```
A + np.eye(A.shape[0]) * np.tril(A).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `np.add.at`

```
y, x = np.tril_indices(len(A), -1)
np.add.at(A, [x,x], A[y,x])
```

This adds the below-diagonal column sums in-place to the corresponding diagonal elements. If these are not guaranteed to be zero, do a

```
A[np.arange(len(A)), np.arange(len(A))] = 0
```

before.

Note that in either case this method does not require the upper triangle to be zero.

If this operation is repeated a lot on matrices of the same size, then indices can be precomputed and flattened for increased performance.

```
# compute once
flatinds = np.ravel_multi_index((y, x), A.shape)
flatdiag = np.ravel_multi_index((x, x), A.shape)
flshdiag = (len(A)+1) * np.arange(len(A))
# use every iteration
Afl = A.ravel()
Afl[flshdiag] = 0 # only if necessary
np.add.at(Afl, flatdiag, Afl[flatinds])
```

Couldn't resist going for a really fast one. It leverages linear indexing and `np.add.reduceat`. Since most sums are along relatively long stretches of column it pays off to do a full (non-lazy) transpose at the beginning and end of the computation. For N >= 5 it consistently beats all the other contenders. If you can keep the matrices involved in column-major (Fortran) order, the two transposes could even be saved in which case it is faster than all the others starting from N == 3.

```
# precompute this (A.shape == (N, N))
finds = np.c_[N * np.arange(N), 1 + (N+1) * np.arange(N)].ravel()[1:-2].copy()

def PPt(A):
    A = A.T.copy()
    Af = A.ravel()
    Af[:-1:N+1] = np.add.reduceat(Af[:-N], finds)[::2]
    Af[-1] = 0
    return A.T.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks a good idea, I will investigate the speed up for this.

Comment: @IanRoberts I hate to admit it but I feel I ought to warn you that in my experience indirect indexing as in this solution is competitive only for small arrays. For anything larger, linearly working down contiguous memory is so optimised and accelerated by SIMD and whatever these special instructions are calld that they can afford summing 10 zeros per actual value and still will be faster... So if your arrays are 50x50 or larger you'll probably be better served with one of the other algorithms.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @IanRoberts Couldn't resist making a really fast one (factor > 10 over the nearest rival for example at N=40). Check the updated answer if you are interested.

Comment: Many thanks - this looks interesting... will check this improved version out.